# Convert a String to int?

Tags: rust

**Note: this question contains deprecated pre-1.0 code! The answer is correct, though.**

To convert a `str` to an `int` in Rust, I can do this:

```
let my_int = from_str::<int>(my_str);
```

The only way I know how to convert a `String` to an `int` is to get a slice of it and then use `from_str` on it like so:

```
let my_int = from_str::<int>(my_string.as_slice());
```

Is there a way to directly convert a `String` to an `int`?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32381414/500207 for non-decimal (i.e., hex).

Comment: Somewhat obvious, but a note to anyone finding this question well after 2014, and wondering why from_str isn't in scope, it isn't in the prelude. `use std::str::FromStr;` fixes that. More on from_str if you'd like. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html#tymethod.from_str

Answer (score 678, accepted):

You can directly convert to an int using the [`str::parse::<T>()` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse), which [returns a Result](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) containing the int.

```
let my_string = "27".to_string();  // `parse()` works with `&str` and `String`!
let my_int = my_string.parse::<i32>().unwrap();
```

You can either specify the type to parse to with the turbofish operator (`::<>`) as shown above or via explicit type annotation:

```
let my_int: i32 = my_string.parse().unwrap();
```

Since `parse()` returns a [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html), it will either be an `Err` if the string couldn't be parsed as the type specified (for example, the string `"peter"` can't be parsed as `i32`), or an `Ok` with the value in it.

Comment: This is very helpful if you already know how to deal with Results. I suggest expanding the answer to accommodate anyone who doesn't.

Comment: _turbofish operator_? Such a cool name. Never heard about that before :)

Comment: @SaeedAhadian It's really the thing's name: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/glossary.html?highlight=turbo#turbofish

Comment: Because it really looks like a fish or a submarine or both: `<i32>()`

Comment: Check out https://turbo.fish/

Answer (score 129):

```
let my_u8: u8 = "42".parse().unwrap();
let my_u32: u32 = "42".parse().unwrap();

// or, to be safe, match the `Err`
match "foobar".parse::<i32>() {
  Ok(n) => do_something_with(n),
  Err(e) => weep_and_moan(),
}
```

[`str::parse::<u32>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse) returns a `Result<u32, core::num::ParseIntError>` and [`Result::unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) "Unwraps a result, yielding the content of an `Ok` [or] panics if the value is an `Err`, with a panic message provided by the `Err`'s value."

[`str::parse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse) is a [generic function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-00-generics.html), hence the type in angle brackets.

Comment: easier to use `if let Ok(n) = "foobar".parse::<i32>() { } else { }`

Answer (score 60):

If you get your string from `stdin().read_line`, you have to trim it first.

```
let my_num: i32 = my_num.trim().parse()
   .expect("please give me correct string number!");
```

Comment: Very important detail!

Comment: Can you explain why ?

Comment: Ok found the answer in rust-book.cs.brown.edu. The trim method on a String instance will eliminate any whitespace at the beginning and end, which we must do to be able to compare the string to the i32, which can only contain numerical data. The user must press enter to satisfy read_line and input their guess, which adds a newline character to the string.

Answer (score 16):

With a recent nightly, you can do this:

```
let my_int = from_str::<int>(&*my_string);
```

What's happening here is that `String` can now be dereferenced into a `str`.  However, the function wants an `&str`, so we have to borrow again.  For reference, I believe this particular pattern (`&*`) is called "cross-borrowing".

Comment: Okay I am not on nightlies but I will accept it as an answer since I actually tried to dereference a `String` at one point and hoped it would work.

Comment: Alternatively, you can express `my_sttring.as_slice()` as `my_string[]` (currently `slicing_syntax` is feature-gated, but most probably some form of it would end up in the language).

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can use the parse method on a String to directly convert it to an integer lik so:

```
let my_string = "42".to_string();
let my_int = my_string.parse::<i32>().unwrap();
```

The parse method returns a Result object, so you will need to handle the case where the string cannot be parsed into an integer. You can use unwrap as shown above to get the value if the parse was successful, or it will panic if the parse failed.

Or you can use the match expression to handle the success and failure cases separately like so:

```
let my_string = "42".to_string();
let my_int = match my_string.parse::<i32>() {
    Ok(n) => n,
    Err(_) => {
        println!("Failed to parse integer");
        0
    },
};
```

FYI, the parse method is available for any type that implements the FromStr trait, which includes all of the integer types (e.g. i32, i64, etc.) as well as many other types such as f32 and bool.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `FromStr` trait's `from_str` method, which is implemented for `i32`:

```
let my_num = i32::from_str("9").unwrap_or(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, no. Why there should be? Just discard the string if you don't need it anymore.

`&str` is more useful than `String` when you need to only read a string, because it is only a view into the original piece of data, not its owner. You can pass it around more easily than `String`, and it is copyable, so it is not consumed by the invoked methods. In this regard it is more general: if you have a `String`, you can pass it to where an `&str` is expected, but if you have `&str`, you can only pass it to functions expecting `String` if you make a new allocation.

You can find more on the differences between these two and when to use them in the [official strings guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-strings.html).

Comment: Well, an obvious reason for why "there should be", in my opinion, is that I wouldn't have to do `.as_slice()` every time I need to do `from_str` on a String. Command line arguments, for example, is one place where I need to do `from_str` on all the args to interpret them as `int`s etc.

Comment: `as_slice()` is only a minor aspect of string handling. For example, you can use slicing syntax (`s[]`) or exploit `Deref` coercion (`&*s`). There is even a proposal which would allow to write just `&s`.

Comment: Ooooh! What would `&s` do for a string? Would it give a `str` back? Could you point me to the proposal?

Comment: First of all, `str` is not what you are working with; it is `&str`. They are different (but related). The former one is a dynamically sized type which you would almost never use directly, while the latter one is a string slice which is a fat pointer. The proposal is called [deref coercions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/241); it would allow to coerce from `&T` to `&U` if `T: Deref<U>`. Since `String: Deref<str>` already, you will be able to obtain `&str` from `String` with just `&`. It is still in discussion but I doubt it'll happen before 1.0 - there's too little time left.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to convert a String  into an Integer right!
here is what I mostly use and that is also mentioned in official documentation..

```
fn main() {

    let char = "23";
    let char : i32 = char.trim().parse().unwrap();
    println!("{}", char + 1);

}
```

This works for both  String and &str 
Hope this will help too.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to other answers, using unwrap_or is another option for quick error handling

```
let my_string = "42";
let my_int = my_string.parse::<i32>().unwrap_or(0);
```

Comment: "Safer" depends on the use-case. Do you want to have a fallback value of zero? If yes, this is not just safer, this is just the correct code and anything else is incorrect. Do you not want it? I'd argue `unwrap()` is safer (offensive programming), or use proper error handling. Falling back to zero will just result in weird bugs later. Also, this is really not the place for this answer, it can maybe be at https://stackoverflow.com/q/63859927/7884305 or at https://stackoverflow.com/q/64996954/7884305. Here it should be at most a comment.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35377982)

Comment: Okay, I'll change that. The link for the documentation : [unwrap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or)

Comment: Instead of calling it safer, I'll label it as just another option.