# Converting a hexadecimal string to a decimal integer

Tags: parsing, hex, rust

I'm writing a Rust program that reads off of an I2C bus and saves the data. When I read the I2C bus, I get hex values like `0x11`, `0x22`, etc.

Right now, I can only handle this as a string and save it as is. Is there a way I can parse this into an integer? Is there any built in function for it?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

In most cases, you want to parse more than one hex byte at once. In those cases, use [the hex crate](https://crates.io/crates/hex).

> parse this into an integer

You want to use [`from_str_radix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i64.html#method.from_str_radix). It's implemented on the integer types.

```
use std::i64;

fn main() {
    let z = i64::from_str_radix("1f", 16);
    println!("{:?}", z);
}
```

If your strings actually have the `0x` prefix, then you will need to skip over them. The best way to do that is via [`trim_start_matches`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim_start_matches) or [`strip_prefix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.strip_prefix):

```
use std::i64;

fn main() {
    let raw = "0x1f";
    let without_prefix = raw.trim_start_matches("0x");
    let z = i64::from_str_radix(without_prefix, 16);
    println!("{:?}", z);
}
```

Comment: That's great, thanks! Just to clarify, the '[2..]' is how you skip the first two spaces? (like over '0' and 'x')

Comment: @tsf144, it is slicing syntax. `&raw[2..]` is a substring of `raw` starting at the second byte of `raw`.

Comment: @tsf144 Just what Vladimir said. The important part is that it is **bytes**. In this case, it looks like you have ASCII-encoded strings, so one character == one byte.

Comment: Does this code fail on a 32-bit machine?  You can do the same thing but replacing `i64` with `isize` so that it supports the architecture of the machine you run it on.

Comment: @JakeIreland no, this does not fail on a 32-bit machine.

Comment: Note that `trim_start_matches` removes the prefix repeatedly, so that would also parse `0x0x0x1f`. You can use `strip_prefix` to remove only once, but will need to differentiate the two cases.

Comment: i am doing something similar with `const someConst: u32 = u32::from_str_radix("10U", 16)` i have an  `expected u32, found Result<u32, ParseIntError>`  error - i've tried unwrapping it etc, does not help  - how to solve this?

Comment: @AthulMuralidhar it's not currently possible to call trait methods for compile-time values, so there is no direct solution.