# How can I convert a hex string to a u8 slice?

Tags: rust

I have a string that looks like this `"090A0B0C"` and I would like to convert it to a slice that looks something like this `[9, 10, 11, 12]`. How would I best go about doing that?

I don't want to convert a single hex char tuple to a single integer value. I want to convert a string consisting of multiple hex char tuples to a slice of multiple integer values.

Comment: 1. We do expect some effort to solve the problem on your own. 2. I don't think you would want to obtain a _slice_, since that one will not own the content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a hexadecimal string to a decimal integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381414/converting-a-hexadecimal-string-to-a-decimal-integer)

Comment: @Stargateur, the part that overlaps with my question was edited in after I had asked my question.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could use the [hex](https://crates.io/crates/hex) crate for that. The [decode](https://docs.rs/hex/0.4.3/hex/fn.decode.html) function looks like it does what you want:

```
fn main() {
    let input = "090A0B0C";

    let decoded = hex::decode(input).expect("Decoding failed");

    println!("{:?}", decoded);
}
```

The above will print `[9, 10, 11, 12]`. Note that `decode` returns a heap allocated `Vec<u8>`, if you want to decode into an array you'd want to use the [`decode_to_slice`](https://docs.rs/hex/0.4.3/hex/fn.decode_to_slice.html) function

```
fn main() {
    let input = "090A0B0C";

    let mut decoded = [0; 4];
    hex::decode_to_slice(input, &mut decoded).expect("Decoding failed");

    println!("{:?}", decoded);
}
```

or the [`FromHex`](https://docs.rs/hex/0.4.3/hex/trait.FromHex.html) trait:

```
use hex::FromHex;

fn main() {
    let input = "090A0B0C";

    let decoded = <[u8; 4]>::from_hex(input).expect("Decoding failed");

    println!("{:?}", decoded);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, just fixed a bug implementing this

Comment: If I could I would give you another up vote. I was trying to do this without realizing that I already had the `hex` crate. I saw your answer a while ago and today it helped me out again!

Answer (score 51):

You can also implement hex encoding and decoding yourself, in case you want to avoid the dependency on the `hex` crate:

```
use std::{fmt::Write, num::ParseIntError};

pub fn decode_hex(s: &str) -> Result<Vec<u8>, ParseIntError> {
    (0..s.len())
        .step_by(2)
        .map(|i| u8::from_str_radix(&s[i..i + 2], 16))
        .collect()
}

pub fn encode_hex(bytes: &[u8]) -> String {
    let mut s = String::with_capacity(bytes.len() * 2);
    for &b in bytes {
        write!(&mut s, "{:02x}", b).unwrap();
    }
    s
}
```

Note that the `decode_hex()` function panics if the string length is odd. I've made a [version with better error handling and an optimised encoder](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=e241493d100ecaadac3c99f37d0f766f) available on the playground.

Comment: your implementtion would be cooler if you wouldn't rely on `fmt` crate. I am compiging with `no_std` flag and I can't use any `std`-based crates

Comment: @Nulik But shouldn't you still be able to use the `core` library even with `no_std`?

Comment: @Seven yep! found out about it this morning.

Comment: You solution is subtle but more versatile than `hex` one. For instance, I was trying to convert the bytes generated by `ed25519_dalek` signature into string, what wasn't possible as it was an 64-bytes long array. By receiving a reference, you shrewdly solve the issue.

Comment: Btw, wouldn't be interesting if you put it into a crate relieving us the burden of copying and pasting your improved version whenever needed?

Comment: @Miere The main point of this answer was to provide two simple functions that can be used if you don't want to use the `hex` crate for some reason, e.g. to reduce compile times. I don't quite know why I wrote the version on the playground. Does my implementation have any advantage over the `hex` crate? If so, I'm happy to put it in a new crate.

Comment: I'll benchmark it. Once I get the results I'll come back to you, @SvenMarnach

Comment: `encode_hex` has an unhandled `Result` from the `write!` macro.

Comment: @Herohtar Writing to a string always returns `Ok(())`. I added `.unwrap()` to make that explicit.

Comment: The step_by method would have saved me a lot of hassle if I had known to use it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without external crates, I think this could also work:

```rust
let result: [u8; 4] = u32::from_str_radix("090A0B0C", 16).unwrap().to_be_bytes();
```