# Why are secp256k1 uncompressed public keys not formatted as expected?

Tags: rust, secp256k1

A small bit of Rust code:

```
let secret_key = SecretKey::from_slice(&rand::thread_rng().gen::<[u8; 32]>()).expect("32 bytes, within curve order");
let public_key = PublicKey::from_secret_key(&secp, &secret_key);
let pk : [u8; 33] = public_key.serialize();
println!("secret_key {:?}", secret_key);
println!("public_key {:?}", public_key);
println!("pk {:x?}", &pk[0..32]);
```

produces output of the form:

```
secret_key SecretKey(03697e6c2168bd5f99f4df7086adf0598f9ae97cced61b072dded9f77a1e837f)
public_key PublicKey(b53c8b4a40a9512037199f4047376905cbe8008be1612e166cb01fa35a60b0c9cd17d5ef86f9c92590fe1125f0fa9b478ca5966eb4be1454b0171adaebe35cfd)
pk [3, c9, b0, 60, 5a, a3, 1f, b0, 6c, 16, 2e, 61, e1, 8b, 0, e8, cb, 5, 69, 37, 47, 40, 9f, 19, 37, 20, 51, a9, 40, 4a, 8b, 3c]
secret_key SecretKey(6d8b97d7bfc4240589d5b523dd5d87096dcbd5b14ea5f780912ab713f6fcfbb3)
public_key PublicKey(3484567baaa84424ceeb76456b6f4ec54efac4c4aa5a06215733aa5d5b2f0d06120a5d05f68dfb5a8b6c204b5efa37201350cfb7905014d239e5fd71e1e23775)
pk [2, 6, d, 2f, 5b, 5d, aa, 33, 57, 21, 6, 5a, aa, c4, c4, fa, 4e, c5, 4e, 6f, 6b, 45, 76, eb, ce, 24, 44, a8, aa, 7b, 56, 84]
secret_key SecretKey(60778385b0110ea8b780f27ca96fce19dfe37d8ad94d2492a0c5595261e9fa49)
public_key PublicKey(db1f88690d138e88544d6a47ed7718cf048abd969cfb79684a3dc19053661bc9c3341094dc84aef237832c993bc16df4b5cf0df27eaa4508ea6f7b67f4062ed7)
pk [3, c9, 1b, 66, 53, 90, c1, 3d, 4a, 68, 79, fb, 9c, 96, bd, 8a, 4, cf, 18, 77, ed, 47, 6a, 4d, 54, 88, 8e, 13, d, 69, 88, 1f]
```

The serialised public key looks as expected, 33 bytes, beginning with 0x02 or 0x03 to denote the sign of the missing Y component.

The X component is present in the uncompressed public key `db1f8869...` but it is offset by one byte and reversed.  This leaves only 31 bytes for the Y component, which does not seem sufficient.

What is the endianess of the uncompressed and compressed public keys?

What have I not understood?

Comment: You probably need a `Display` trait instead, i.e. `println!("secret_key {}", secret_key);`

Comment: @Kitsu Thanks, but the display trait just outputs the public key in the same compressed format as serialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The “offset by one byte” issue is because you have your slice indexes wrong. The second value is *one past* the last index to be included, so instead of `&pk[0..32]` you want `&pk[0..33]`, or since that is the entire array just `&pk[..]`.

The reversed bytes are because the debug output for the public key simply dumps the internal representation of the key. Internally the key is held as an array of `int64`s which is copied directly into a char array, so on a little endian system this will look like the bytes are reversed*. When using `serialize` (or the `{}` format specifier) the key is correctly formatted with the most significant byte first.

*It’s actually a bit more complicated than that, calculations are done on an array of ints using 52 bits, and are then packed into a denser “storage” form that uses all 64 bits.

Comment: Thanks, today I learned that the Rust ranges are exclusive of the second bound, like a `for` loop in C.

Answer (score 2):

There is another method in `secp256k1` crate that you can call on the public key to get the uncompressed key called `serialize_uncompressed()`. (You would then need to drop the first byte to have a 64 byte key).