# Rust: Convert sha256 to hex

Tags: rust, hex, sha256

I have following output in sha256 online:

[image: Value as hex]

But in my rust when i do

```
 let mut hasher = Sha256::default();

 hasher.update(input_data.secret);

 let input_secret_hash: String = format!("{:x}", hasher.finalize());
```

where **input_data.secret == 75ca0e2daaf49840ddce9456378efbc95e97ed2566226edca2d73ca1c50450fc**

i receive
**46fe3a4fc1480dfdc1b23906c10cb49eee043733c6c410081aa245234c05e4cb**

which is the value as text:

[[image: Value as text2]

How i'm able to receive value as the hex screenshot example

Comment: You need to [convert you hex string to a binary slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52987181/how-can-i-convert-a-hex-string-to-a-u8-slice/52992629#52992629) before hashing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just decode your hex into the raw bytes:

```rust
use hex;
...
let message: Vec<u8> = hex::decode("75ca0e2daaf49840ddce9456378efbc95e97ed2566226edca2d73ca1c50450fc")
    .expect("Invalid Hex String");
...
hasher.update(&message);
...
```