# Getting pointer by &str

Tags: pointers, rust, unsafe

Consider this pseudocode:

```
    let k = 10;
    let ptr = &k as *const k;
    println!("{:p}", ptr); // prints address of pointer
    let addr = format!("{:p}", ptr);

    super-unsafe {
    // this would obviously be super unsafe. It may even cause a STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION if you try getting memory from a page that the OS didn't allocate to the program!

    let ptr_gen = PointerFactory::from_str(addr.as_str()); 

    assert_eq!(k, *ptr_gen);
    }
```

The pseudocode gets the idea across: I want to be able to get a pointer to a certain memory address by its &str representation. Is this... possible?

Comment: Why can't you just turn the string representation back to an unsigned integer first?

Comment: Ah, would this be done via transmute or something under std::mem or std::ptr?

Comment: Also, please correct me if I'm wrong as I learn low-level coding, but aren't all pointers the same size in memory unto themselves? (needed to know how many bits to use for unsigned)

Comment: The essentials here are answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381414/converting-a-hexadecimal-string-to-a-decimal-integer), using `from_str_radix()` to convert e.g. "0xdeadbeef" to an integer; from there you cast to a ptr* and hope nobody is looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So essentially what you want to do is parse the string back to an integer (`usize`) and then interpret that value as a pointer/reference<sup>†</sup>:

```rust
fn main()
{
    let i = 12i32;
    let r = format!("{:p}", &i);


    let x = unsafe
    {
        let r = r.trim_start_matches("0x");
        &*(usize::from_str_radix(&r, 16).unwrap() as *const i32)
    };

    println!("{}", x);
}
```

You can try this yourself in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=66ff20c75866a7af8477474e701a5b39).

<sup>†</sup>As you can see, you don't even need to cast your reference into a raw pointer, the `{:p}` formatter takes care of representing it as a memory location (index).

---

**Update**: As E_net4 mentioned this in the comment section, it is better to use `usize` here, which is architecture defined unlike the machine sized one.  The `transmute` was not necessary, so I removed it.  The third point about undefined behaviour however seems obvious to whomever tries to do something like the above.  This answer provides a way to achieve what the OP asked for which doesn't mean this should be used for anything else than academic/experimental purposes :)

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad we have this answered on SO now. Although it's not unexpected when rust is using magnum over a baloon for protection.

Comment: No worries, really, but be careful whatever you are going to use it for!  (I warned you ;))  Also, I rejected your edit, because that is not helping the understanding IMO.  I would suggest you to post it as a separate answer if you like.

Comment: With mutexes, and some graphs, I'm sure I'll be able to pull out before anything unwanted happens ;). Thank you, and no probs with the edit.

Comment: Worth mentioning that there are multiple problems in this solution: 1. it only works for 64-bit pointer width targets, one should use `usize` instead of `u64`; 2. one doesn't need `transmute`, you can cast the `usize` value to a raw pointer with `as` and dereference it instead; 3. this creates a reference with n unbounded lifetime, so it can live longer than the original value. See [playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=6bee25c3e9243d30f93e5f2c9a4b3e57) with suggested changes + UB.

Comment: Very interesting addition Enet. Thanks!