# Why is my program panicking although the datatype is same?

Tags: rust

Why is my program generating

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err`
> value: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', src/main.rs:68:54 note:
> run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a
> backtrace

when I enter the generated hash it panics instead of passing control to if {..}.

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Hello user! Please cast your input ");
    let userinput: u64 = user_input();
    let mut hasher_two = DefaultHasher::new();
    let vecdata = [0x09, 0x06, 0xba, 0x67, 0x76];
    hasher_two.write(&vecdata);
    let final_check = hasher_two.finish();

    if final_check == userinput {
        correct_file_creation();
    } else {
        wrong_file_creation();
    }
}

pub fn user_input() -> u64 {
    let mut userinput = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut userinput).unwrap();
    let userinputinteger: i32 = userinput.trim().parse().unwrap();
    return userinputinteger as u64;
}
```

Comment: You didn't show the relevant code or say what the input is. Post a [mcve].

Comment: The input is : 66d3f00739bafb9d

Comment: Maybe you want to fix the indentation of your code to make it more readable.

Comment: And what do you expect to happen when you parse that into a `ì32`?

Comment: Two points: first `parse::<i32>` parses _decimal_ numbers but your input is hexadecimal. Second `66d3f00739bafb9d` doesn't fit in an `i32` (and why go through an `i32` in the first place if you want to return a `u64` anyway?) → `return u64::from_str_radix (userinput.trim(), 16).unwrap()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific, since you're not parsing a normal number.

You'll need to tell rust that you want to parse a hex string.

See this answer on how to do that:

[Converting a hexadecimal string to a decimal integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381414/converting-a-hexadecimal-string-to-a-decimal-integer)

I do not know anything about rust but your error message suggests that because the error is in `ParseIntError` with a second clue in that error message: `kind: InvalidDigit` which means that it has no idea what an `a` or `f` is doing in your string that's supposed to be an integer.