# Error Reading & Calculating Quotient

Tags: types, rust

I'm a Rust novice and trying to read in two numbers and calculate their quotient:

```
use std::io;

enum Option<T> {
    None,
    Some(T),
}

fn safe_div(n: i32, d: i32) -> Option<i32> {
    if d == 0 {
        return None;
    }
    return Some(n / d);
}

fn main() {
    println!("Please input your numerator.");
    let mut numerator = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut numerator)
        .expect("Failed to read line");
    println!("Please input your denominator.");
    let mut denominator = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut denominator)
        .expect("Failed to read line");
    match safe_div(numerator, denominator) {
        None => println!("Can't divide by zero!"),
        Some(v) => println!("Quotient is {}", v),
    }
}
```

but I am getting the following error repeated several times when I try to compile it:

> src/safe_div.rs:12:12: 12:21 error: mismatched types:
>    expected `Option<i32>`,
>       found `std::option::Option<i32>`
>   (expected enum `Option`,
>       found enum `std::option::Option`) [E0308]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, any Rust application includes *the prelude*. You can turn it off, but if you do not, it pulls in the `::std::option::Option<T>` type as well as its variants `None` and `Some` into scope.

Unless someone decides to create something using those names, in which case the newly defined items take priority.

Your problem here is that you have only half-shadowed the standard `Option`:

- you defined `Option`, which takes precedence over `::std::option::Option`
- you did NOT pull `None` and `Some` into the same scope (they are nested in the `Option` scope), whereas `::std::option::Option::{None, Some}` are there via the prelude

The result is that `Option` refers to `::Option` while `None` and `Some` refer to `::std::option::Option::None` and `::std::option::Option::Some` respectively. It's a mess.

One solution, if you really *want* the override, is to import `None` and `Some` yourself:

```
enum Option<T> {
    None,
    Some(T)
}

use Option::{None, Some};
```

The other is NOT to redefine `Option`.

Once you apply either fix, you'll realize that you are passing strings as arguments to `safe_div`, you can use `.parse().expect("Expected i32")` to parse them as integers.

Comment: I tried this fix and the compile errors go away but it gives me the runtime error instead: `thread '<main>' panicked at 'Expected i32'` and dies rather than printing the quotient.

Answer (score 0):

*You* don't need to define `Option`; it's [already part of the standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html). Remove the definition and it will get past that error. The next error is that you have a `String` that you are trying to use as a number [without parsing it first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27043268/155423).

I'd **strongly recommend** that you go back and read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/) again. The first chapters, especially the guessing game, are targeted at exactly this level of introduction.

Comment: @wogsland please continue reading my answer. There are only **3** sentences in the first paragraph and the *third sentence* describes that error.

Comment: @wogsland As this is a site for professional programmers, I'd hope that the target audience would read the introductory documentation for a language or framework and be able to compose larger solutions out of smaller components. Besides, I **linked to an existing answer** on how to parse strings; would you prefer that an answerer write *all* of your code for you?

Comment: Quick note: A site for *enthusiast* and professional programmers ;)