# Parsing an url in Iron and getting a dynamic part

Tags: rust, iron

I have 2 routes in Iron:

1. `/something/:some_int` # integer
2. `/something2/:some_str` # string

How can I get these `:some_{int, str}` parts of them?

```
fn my_something_int_route_handler(req: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    let ref query = req.extensions.get::<Router>().unwrap().find("query").unwrap_or("/");

    //what next ???
    // how can I get the ":some_int" from :/something/:some_int
```

```
fn my_something2_str_route_handler(req: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    let ref query = req.extensions.get::<Router>().unwrap().find("query").unwrap_or("/");

    // how can I get the ":some_str" from :/something/:some_str
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [router crate](https://crates.io/crates/router):

```
let mut router = Router::new();
router.get("/users/:user_id", user_show, "user_show");
let _server = Iron::new(router).http(("127.0.0.1", 8787)).unwrap();
```

Inside your handler, you get a reference to the `Router`'s [`Params`](https://docs.rs/router/0.5.1/router/struct.Params.html) which lets you get the value for each named parameter. Note that the argument to `Params::find` matches the names assigned when the route was defined:

```
fn user_show(req: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    let router = req.extensions.get::<Router>()
        .expect("Unable to get router");
    user_id = router.find("user_id")
        .expect("A user id is required");
}
```

One you have a parameter as string, you [parse it into a number like anywhere else in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27043268/155423).