# How to deserialise a number from an XML attribute using serde?

Tags: rust, serde

I want to deserialize a number (for example, `u32`) from an XML attribute.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_xml_rs as serde_xml;


#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(rename = "objects")]
pub struct Objects {
    pub foo: u32
}

fn main() {
    let result_string = r#"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <objects foo="42"></objects>"#;
    let deserialized: Objects= serde_xml::deserialize(result_string.as_bytes()).expect("Parse error!");
}
```

But after execution, I get the following error

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Parse error!: invalid type: string "42", expected u32'
```

I know about `#[serde(deserialize_with="...")]` annotation, but is there an easier way, (for example use `serde_xml_rs` crate)?

Comment: Without the attribute, you would need to express the types in some sort of schema. But unfortunately `serde_xml_rs`  does not support schema or DTD.

Comment: Maybe `Option<u32>` would work to handle non-numeric cases

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043268/convert-a-string-to-int-in-rust

Why not just append the str::parse::<u32> to your deserialize function?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `0.2.1`. Add to Cargo.toml:

```
serde-xml-rs = { git= "https://github.com/RReverser/serde-xml-rs.git"}
```

Using serde-xml-rs from master fixes this issue.