# How to get a value from a Result?

Tags: rust

How can I get the value of a `struct` which is returned in a `Result` from another function? Example below.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Keypair(ed25519_dalek::Keypair);

pub fn keypair_from_seed(seed: &[u8]) -> Result<Keypair, Box<dyn error::Error>> {
    let dalek_keypair = ed25519_dalek::Keypair { secret, public };
    Ok(Keypair(dalek_keypair))
}
```

```
fn main(){
  //here seed_bytes is mnemonics
  let sk = keypair_from_seed(&seed_bytes);
  //sk contains the secret key and public key, i want to extract it different secret key & public key
}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you feel very confident

```rust
let sk = keypair_from_seed(&seed_bytes).unwrap();
```

or

```rust
let sk = keypair_from_seed(&seed_bytes).expect("my own failure message");
```

However, it is recommended to proceed like this

```rust
if let Ok(sk) = keypair_from_seed(&seed_bytes) {
    // ... use sk ...
} else {
    // ... sk is not available, may be should
    // we warn the user, ask for an alternative ... 
}
```

or, if you want to explicitly handle the error

```rust
match keypair_from_seed(&seed_bytes) {
    Ok(sk) => { 
        // ... use sk ...
    },
    Err(e) => {
        // ... sk is not available, and e explains why ...
    },
}
```

Note that, if the function containing these lines is also
able to return an error, you can just propagate it with
the `?` notation (if the error returned by
`keypair_from_seed()` is convertible into the error returned
by your function)

```rust
let sk = keypair_from_seed(&seed_bytes)?;
```

see
[`unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap),
[`expect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect),
[`if let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/flow_control/if_let.html),
[`match`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/flow_control/match.html),
[`?`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/error/result/enter_question_mark.html)

Comment: `.unwarp_err() to extract the error value`

Answer (score 10):

Lets look the definition of `Result` in Rust documentation

```
enum Result<T, E> {
   Ok(T),
   Err(E),
}
```

So a `Result` is either `Ok` which contains a value with type `T`, or `Err` which contains a value with type `E`.

You have couple options to extract the value.

#### 1- result.unwrap() or result.expect("error message")

This function returns the `Ok` value if result is `Ok` or panics the program (program is terminated). If you are sure that it doesn't contain error or you just want to write the correct case first and deal with error handling later it makes sense but you shouldn't use it all the time since it directly crashes the app when the value is not `Ok`.
You can use it like this

```
let val = result.unwrap();
// or
let val = result.expect("oops not Ok");
```

Only difference of `expect` you can provide the error message yourself instead of the standard error message of `unwrap`.

#### 2- Pattern matching

In Rust, pattern matching is used for `enum` types so that user can do the necessary thing based on the current variant of the enum. You can use it like this

```
match result {
    Ok(val) => {
        // Use val here....
    },
    Err(err) => {
        // Do something with the error if you want
    }
}
```

If you are going to handle only one variant, you can also use `if let` statement like this

```
if let Some(val) = result {
    // Do something with val
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The returned result from the function is of the type `Result<Keypair, Box<dyn error::Error>>`.

There are multiple ways to extract a result from the `Result` container. Basically rust wants you to check for any errors and handle it. If no errors, you can extract the result and use it.

```
if let Ok(sk) = keypair_from_seed(&seed) {
    let public = sk.0.public;
    let secret = sk.0.secret;
    /* use your keys */
}
```

Notice the `sk.0` since you are using a struct of a tuple type. If your struct had multiple variables, something like

```
pub struct KeyTuple(ed25519_dalek::Keypair, i32, &str);
```

You would have used it as

```
let kt = keytuple_from_seed(&seed).unwrap();
let kp: ed25519_dalek::Keypair = kt.0;
let le: i32 = kt.1;
let st: &str = kt.2;
```

Comment: The problem with `if let` here is the lack of an `else`. If you really expect the result to be `Ok`, it's probably not sensible to proceed on `Err` as if you were successful. It depends on the context, obviously, which is why `if let` exists, but I would recommend `match` here to encourage doing something sensible in the `Err` case.

Comment: Yes, I understand, match would be a more idomatic way to do it, but my answer stresses on the way to extract the members of they keypair object which I believe the OP is asking for. Anyways, other answers have a better way to handle the Result extraction part.