# How to check if error type matches a specific error type in Rust?

Tags: rust

So I have this custom error,

```
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum XError {
  TagNotFound,
}

impl std::error::Error for XError {}

impl fmt::Display for XError {
  fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
    match self {
      XError::TagNotFound => write!(f, "couldn't find tag"),
    }
  }
}
```

And then I have a function `pub fn validate() -> Result<String, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>`.

Now in my test, how do I check if error returned by `validate` is `XError::TagNotFound`?

I tried doing,

```
let b = validate(param)
  .unwrap_err()
  .downcast_ref::<XError::TagNotFound>();
```

But I get this `expected type, found variant "XError::TagNotFound" not a type`.

Comment: Not sure, but can't you just access the box content and match it like you've already done?

Comment: Are you looking for `matches!(err, XError::TagNotFound)` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I conditionally check if an enum is one variant or another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51429501/how-do-i-conditionally-check-if-an-enum-is-one-variant-or-another)

Comment: @user202729 I am sorry I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Do you mean to do this `matches!(a.unwrap_err(), XError::TagNotFound)`? This doesn't work. I get `mismatched types
expected struct "Box<dyn std::error::Error>" found enum "XError"`.

Comment: I mean [rust - How to get a value from a Result? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63859927/how-to-get-a-value-from-a-result) → [rust - How do I get an owned value out of a `Box`? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42264041/how-do-i-get-an-owned-value-out-of-a-box) → do what you did already. Did I miss something?

Comment: You have to do the matches from an error, which you can handle like other enum values.

Comment: I would suggest not boxing errors, but instead having an enum that wraps all the possible errors you might encounter. Then you can just match on it. Furthermore, it should be slightly more performant because it won't allocate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `XError::TagNotFound` is not a type, as the error message says. It's a *variant* of the `XError` enum.

You have a `Box<dyn Error>`, and you want to check whether that error is `XError::TagNotFound`. This check consists of two steps:

1. Downcasting from `Box<dyn Error>` to `XError`, if possible.
2. Checking whether the downcasted `XError` is `XError::TagNotFound`.

Step 1 can be performed using `my_error.downcast_ref::<XError>()`, which will return an `Option<&XError>`. Step 2 is normal pattern matching, and can be performed with `if let`, `match` or the `matches!()` macro, whatever you prefer. Here is one option:

```
if let Some(&XError::TagNotFound) = my_error.downcast_ref::<XError>() {
    // handle error
}
```

In a unit test, using the `matches!()` macro is probably more appropriate:

```
assert!(matches!(my_error.downcast_ref::<XError>(), Some(&XError::TagNotFound));
```

Comment: That helps. Thank you so much.

Comment: Just adding that in nightly we have [`assert_matches!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/assert_matches/macro.assert_matches.html)