# How to handle error in unwrap() function?

Tags: rust

What is the best way to handle the error when reading arguments from the CLI?

For example, when the second argument is not provided in the following code?

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let filename = env::args().nth(0).unwrap();
    let other_argument = env::args().nth(1).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63860291/11527076) could help. It's about `Result/Ok/Err` but the same logic applies to `Option/Some/None`.

Comment: `unwrap` is designed to simply crash (or more accurately, panic) if the result is `None`. There are many other methods/techniques you can use to handle that case more elegantly, as seen in the post @prog-fh links to. But the short answer is "don't use `unwrap` unless you want this behaviour".

Comment: You handle error cases by not using `unwrap()` and instead writing some code to handle it. What that code looks like depends on what you want to do; should the program print an error message and exit? Use a default value and continue? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to use the `match` to differentiate between the value of enums.
An example which illustrates this approach for `Options` like you might need it for your arguments (you could also use different approaches) and `Result`

```
use std::env;
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    // match 1
    // handle Options https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html using match
    match env::args().nth(1) {
        Some(v) => {
            println!("arg 1: {:?}", v);

            // match 2
            // handle Result https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/ using match
            match fs::read_to_string(&v) {
                Ok(contents) => println!("{}", contents),
                Err(e) => println!("{}", e),
            };
        }
        None => {
            println!("you have not passed an argument.");
        }
    }
}
```

Like already others wrote, I can also really recommend the crate https://docs.rs/structopt/latest/structopt/ in order to evaluate command line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that if the user does not input those arguments then you probably want the program to crash.

You can use `expect` which is a nice alternative to `unwrap` because it lets you specify the error message when crashing.

```
let filename = env::args().nth(0).expect("Did not provide the filename argument");
```

https://learning-rust.github.io/docs/e4.unwrap_and_expect.html

If you want the "best" way to deal with this, I recomment using the structopt library for handling program arguments.

https://lib.rs/crates/structopt

Fyi: not sure if this is your intended behavior but the 0th argument is actually the name of the program being executed rather than the first argument on the command line.