# Rust: Iterate through a folder and open each file

Tags: multithreading, rust, iterator

I am brand new to Rust (week 1) and am having trouble accessing a variable inside an iterator. I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate question. I am not even sure how to intelligently ask this question.

Also, can someone please point me in the right direction as to how to process each file in a different thread.

```
let files = fs::read_dir(path).unwrap();

for file_name in files {
   println!("Processing File: {}", file_name.unwrap().path().display());
   // how do I pass the file name to open?
   // everything I try I get a 'file_name moved due to this method call' error
   let file = File::open(file_name.....).expect("Unable to open file");

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are investigating this problem for the first time, I guess a step-by-step example can help you.
Of course, there exist much shorter ways to do the equivalent (in particular, [this function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read.html) is very convenient in order to open and read all the content in a single call).

Since there are many interactions with the underlying system, almost each operation might fail.
I decided to handle explicitly the error each time with an explicit `match` statement.
Again, there exist [many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63860291/11527076) to handle the successes/failures.

```rust
use std::io::Read; // for .read_to_end()

fn main() {
    let path = ".";
    let entries = std::fs::read_dir(path).unwrap();
    for entry in entries {
        match entry {
            Ok(entry) => {
                println!("Processing entry: {:?}", entry);
                let file = std::fs::File::open(entry.path());
                match file {
                    Ok(mut file) => {
                        let mut buffer = Vec::new();
                        let content = file.read_to_end(&mut buffer);
                        match content {
                            Ok(sz) => {
                                println!("  got {} bytes", sz);
                                // we should work with buffer here
                            }
                            Err(e) => {
                                println!("  read error: {:?}", e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Err(e) => {
                        println!("  open error: {:?}", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("  entry error: {:?}", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
/*
Processing entry: DirEntry("./.cargo")
  read error: Os { code: 21, kind: IsADirectory, message: "Is a directory" }
Processing entry: DirEntry("./src")
  read error: Os { code: 21, kind: IsADirectory, message: "Is a directory" }
Processing entry: DirEntry("./Cargo.toml")
  got 972 bytes
Processing entry: DirEntry("./target")
  read error: Os { code: 21, kind: IsADirectory, message: "Is a directory" }
Processing entry: DirEntry("./SAVE_rust-toolchain")
  got 8 bytes
Processing entry: DirEntry("./Cargo.lock")
  got 154 bytes
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I think the rust compiler gives you a pretty helpful message!

use of moved value: `file_name`
value used here after move
main.rs(11, 34): `file_name` moved due to this method call
main.rs(11, 24): help: consider calling `.as_ref()` or `.as_mut()` to borrow the type's contents
main.rs(10, 9): move occurs because `file_name` has type `Result<DirEntry, std::io::Error>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
result.rs(1083, 19): `Result::<T, E>::unwrap` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `file_name`

Just use as_ref() and the filename is passed as a reference instead of being moved.

```
let files = fs::read_dir(path).unwrap();

for file_name in files {
    println!("{}", file_name.as_ref().unwrap().path().display());
    let file = File::open(file_name.unwrap().path()).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: The line: let file = File::open(file_name.unwrap().path()).unwrap();  
Does not work. If I try: file_name.unwrap().path().as_ref(), I get a type must be known at this point error/