# How can I pull data out of an Option for independent use?

Tags: rust, enums, pattern-matching, option-type

Is there a way to 'pull' data out of an `Option`? I have an API call that returns `Some(HashMap)`. I want to use the `HashMap` as if it weren't inside `Some` and play with the data.

Based on what I've read, it looks like `Some(...)` is only good for match comparisons and some built-in functions.

Simple API call pulled from crate docs:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let resp = reqwest::blocking::get("https://httpbin.org/ip")?
        .json::<HashMap<String, String>>()?;
    println!("{:#?}", resp.get("origin"));
    Ok(())
}
```

Result:

```
Some("75.69.138.107")
```

Comment: Some examples are fully documented here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/option_unwrap.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
if let Some(origin) = resp.get("origin") {
    // use origin
}
```

If you can guarantee that it's impossible for the value to be `None`, then you can use:

```
let origin = resp.get("origin").unwrap();
```

Or:

```
let origin = resp.get("origin").expect("This shouldn't be possible!");
```

And, since your function returns a `Result`:

```
let origin = resp.get("origin").ok_or("This shouldn't be possible!")?;
```

Or with a custom error type:

```
let origin = resp.get("origin").ok_or(MyError::DoesntExist)?;
```

Answer (score 11):

The most common way is with `if let`:

```
if let Some(origin) = resp.get("origin") {
    origin.do_stuff()
}
```

For more fine grained control, you can use pattern matching:

```rust
match resp.get("origin") {
    Some(origin) => origin.do_stuff(),
    None => panic!("origin not found!")
}
```

You could also use `unwrap`, which will give you the underlying value of the option, or `panic` if it is `None`:

```
let origin = resp.get("origin").unwrap();
```

You can customize the `panic` message with `expect`:

```
let origin = resp.get("origin").expect("Oops!");
```

Or compute a default value with `unwrap_or`:

```rust
let origin = resp.get("origin").unwrap_or(&String::from("192.168.0.1"));
```

You can also return an error instead of panicking:

```rust
let origin = resp.get("origin").ok_or(Error::UnknownOrigin)?;
```

Answer (score 8):

Your options are a plenty.

```rust
if let Some(origin) = resp.get("origin") {
    // do stuff using origin
}
```

```rust
origin = resp.get("origin").unwrap()
// will panic if None
```

```rust
resp.get("origin").map(|origin| {
    // do stuff using inner value, returning another option
})
```

```rust
resp.get("origin").and_then(|origin| {
    // same as map but short-circuits if there is no inner value
})
```

Comment: both `map` and `and_then` "short-circuit" if the value is `None`, `and_then` is just a shorthand for `map(...).flatten()` if the functor itself returns an `Option`

Comment: @kmdreko A bit odd that the docs specify this behaviour for `and_then` but don't mention it for `map`

Comment: OTOH, what do you expect it to do if it does _not_ short-circuit? It can't call the closure if there is no value to give the `origin` argument…

Answer (score 0):

I'll try and provide an explanation here with a more generic example as none of the answers or documentation really helped me understand the solution.

Think of `Option<T>` as requiring an `if` statement to check if the value is not null:

> *if* this thing is not null, then consider it usable

In order to determine if it is usable you have to unwrap it.

Assume we have an `Option<str>` with the variable name `someone`:

```
match someone {
  None => {
    println!("no-one is here");
  }
  Some(name) => {
    println!("hello {name}");
  }
}
// name is not accessible here
```

Note that `Some` contains the `str` value of the `Option<str>` variable, and makes it usable under a different variable name - `name` - which can only be used inside the scope of `Some`.

A cleaner way of writing it which might be more similar to `if else` is `if let Some`:

```
if let Some(name) = someone {
    println!("hi {name}");
    // more logic involving name
}
```

Hopefully this helps some people who are still a bit confused.

Edit: here is a working gist: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=15817254d46340599b585b5cf7f1b0c4