# Optional parameter / null handling

Tags: rust

I have a function which takes 4 nullable `BigUint` parameters and return a tuple of `Option` type. I am calling this function in an iterative fashion and I am trying to figure how to handle `None` values as I want to treat them explicitly. I have the following uncompilable code:

```
use num_bigint::BigUint; // 0.4.0

fn add_one(
    px: &Option<BigUint>,
    py: &Option<BigUint>,
    qx: &Option<BigUint>,
    qy: &Option<BigUint>,
) -> (Option<BigUint>, Option<BigUint>) {
    if px.is_none() && py.is_none() {
        (*qx, *qy)
    } else if px == qx {
        (None, None)
    } else {
        (px + 1u32, py + 1u32)
    }
}
```

With the error:

```
error[E0369]: cannot add `u32` to `&Option<BigUint>`
  --> src/lib.rs:14:13
   |
14 |         (px + 1u32, py + 1u32)
   |          -- ^ ---- u32
   |          |
   |          &Option<BigUint>

error[E0369]: cannot add `u32` to `&Option<BigUint>`
  --> src/lib.rs:14:24
   |
14 |         (px + 1u32, py + 1u32)
   |                     -- ^ ---- u32
   |                     |
   |                     &Option<BigUint>
```

How do I evaluate `Option` to its corresponding type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust, How can I 'pull' data out of <Option> Some() for independent use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64996954/rust-how-can-i-pull-data-out-of-option-some-for-independent-use)

Answer (score 1):

First, it's important to remember that an `Option<T>` is *not* a `T`. Even if it contains one, it's not itself one. It's a box which may or may not be empty. This is in contrast to a language like Kotlin where `T?` is actually a `T` or possibly `null`.

With that out of the way, it sounds like you want to take `px` and `py` and, if they contain values, add one to them, and if they don't then leave them empty. That's a perfect use case for [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map).

```
(px.map(|x| x+1u32), py.map(|x| x+1u32))
```

As a general piece of advice, in Java and Kotlin you're going to spend a lot of time using if statements and imperative logic to suss out your null values. In Rust, you're primarily going to do that using the standard library methods on [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html). Get to know them; they're really quite helpful and encompass a lot of patterns you use frequently that, in other languages, might just be done with copious explicit null-checks.

Comment: I was going to suggest using `match` instead. `if px.is_none() && py.is_none() {` can easily be replaced by `match (px, py) { (None, None) => ...`.