# How to receive optional tuple return values

Tags: rust, tuples, return-value

I have a function that looks like this:

```
fn some_func() -> Option<(String, i32)>
```

When I tried to do this:

```
let (a, b) = some_func();
```

The compiler throws this error:

```
expected enum `Option`, found tuple
```

How can I receive the return values from the function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pull data out of an Option for independent use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64996954/how-can-i-pull-data-out-of-an-option-for-independent-use)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `Some()` on `some_func()` to access either the values (or in the event that there are no values, `None()`).

The idiomatic way to do this in Rust is with a `match` statement.

```
match some_func() {
    Some((x, y)) => println!("{} {}", x, y),
    None => panic!("no vals"),
}
```

Or if you wanna use assignment like in your example (but it won't handle `None`):

```
let (a, b) = some_func().unwrap();
println!("{} {}", a, b);
```

Playground [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9cfdcc248fd964b78845da68fe09c3c8).

And an updated playground with `.expect()` instead of `.unwrap()` [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=435dd2d4ec78d43e2698c81016a6af7e).

The larger point being that it is unlikely that you want to proceed in this block if `(a, b)` is `None`.

Comment: But does the second example throw an error when None is returned?

Comment: There will be an error if you call `unwrap()` on `None`, yeah. That's why pattern matching makes more sense.

Comment: `some_func()?` will float up the None if your own function returns an `Option`.
Or you can do `some_func().ok_or("missing foo")?` if your function returns a `Result`. Finally, there is also `if let Some((a,b)) = some_func() { ... }` which will only execute the block if something is returned and do nothing if None.