# how to bool a string contains a digit between an another digit

Tags: rust, boolean, contains

I want to know if it possible to boolean a String contains a digit between an another digit
to set a variable after

the code i tried

```rust
pub fn ram() -> String {
    let okmdr = Command::new("wmic").arg("memorychip").arg("get").arg("speed").output().unwrap_or_else(|e| panic!("impossible d'obtenir le type et la vitesse de la RAM"));
    let speed = String::from_utf8_lossy(&okmdr.stdout).to_string();
    let split: Vec<String> = speed.split_inclusive("Speed").map(|s| s.to_string()).collect();
    let splitjsp: Vec<String> = split[1].split(" ").map(|o| o.to_string()).collect();
    let jsp = if splitjsp[2].contains(1601..3200) { String::from("DDR4") } else if splitjsp[2].contains(0..1600) { String::from("DDR3") } else { String::from("Unknown")};
    jsp
}
```

the error i got :

```rust
let jsp = if splitjsp[2].contains(1601..3200) { String::from("DDR4") } else if splitjsp[2].contains(0..1600) { String::from("DDR3") }...
                         -------- ^^^^^^^^^^ expected an `FnMut<(char,)>` closure, found `std::ops::Range<{integer}>`
                         |
      required by a bound introduced by this call
```

Comment: How are 1601 and 3200 digits? Did you mean "number"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a String to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043268/convert-a-string-to-int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your English is a bit garbled, so let me see if I got that right: You want to check if some number is contained in an interval, but that number is currently stored in a string?

Well, currently your code is calling [`str::contains`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.contains) which can check whether a string contains e.g. a substring or character. For example, you can test whether `"sd"` is contained in `"asdf"` (yes). That is not what you want.

You'll have to use

- [`str::parse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse)
- [`Range::contains`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/struct.Range.html#method.contains)

Do note that a Rust range `a..b` contains `a`, but doesn't contain `b`. If you want a range that contains both ends, you want `a..=b`.

So you might do something like:

```rust
let jsp2 = splitjsp[2].parse().expect("JSP output format: expected integer in line 3");
if (1601..=3200).contains(&jsp2) {
    …
```

but it might be more elegant to use a match:

```rust
match jsp2 {
    0..1601 => …,
    1601..3201 => …,
    _ => …,
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=907bf710a1895b9c0c19f77ecdaf1a0b)